# Check if a given integer is power of two

Tags: java, interview-questions, bitwise

> Given an integer, check if it's the power of two.

```
class Main {
  static class Solution {
    private final boolean answer;

    Solution(int num) {
      if (num <= 0) {
        answer = false;
      }
      else if ((num & (num - 1)) == 0) {
        answer = true;
      }
      else {
        answer = false;
      }
    }

    public boolean isPowerOfTwo() {
      return answer;
    }
  }

  public static void runTests() {
    // Falsy
    System.out.println(new Solution(-1).isPowerOfTwo());
    System.out.println(new Solution(0).isPowerOfTwo());
    System.out.println(new Solution(Integer.MAX_VALUE).isPowerOfTwo());
    System.out.println(new Solution(Integer.MIN_VALUE).isPowerOfTwo());

    //Truthy
    System.out.println(new Solution(1).isPowerOfTwo());
    System.out.println(new Solution(128).isPowerOfTwo());
    System.out.println(new Solution(1024).isPowerOfTwo());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    runTests();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Code organization

There is nothing in the description and the posted code to justify storing the result of the "is power of 2" calculation in a class.
It would be better to simply return it.
The code is also simple enough that you could collapse the if-else chain to a single line:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int num) {
    return num > 0 && (num & (num - 1)) == 0;
}
```

#### Testing

I suggest to look into proper unit testing methods,
for example JUnit4 which comes bundled in most IDEs.
The tests you wrote in main would look like this using JUnit4:

```
private boolean isPowerOfTwo(int num) {
    return Solution.isPowerOfTwo(num);
}

@Test
public void minus1_should_not_be_power_of_2() {
    assertFalse(isPowerOfTwo(-1));
}

@Test
public void zero_should_not_be_power_of_2() {
    assertFalse(isPowerOfTwo(0));
}

// ... and so on
```

Comment: Most of the questions I post here is under the assumption that there is a interview going on and I am doing some online coding hence I cannot have the testing framework, having said that I was just experimenting with creating a class for each algorithm something which I read in the Sedgwick's book.

Comment: You can write proper unit tests on a whiteboard just as you can write a main method with tests. You cannot run either of them. But you will get plus points for the good habit of proper unit testing.

Comment: I typically use online editors such as `https://repl.it/languages/java` and I don't think I can run tests on them. I really believe in testing but what to do when environment doesn't support it?

Comment: In environments that don't support it, you could imitate it. You could for example implement simple `assert*` methods that will throw an exception on failure. This is theoretically speaking. In an online editor as you mentioned, indeed I wouldn't bother. You should have mentioned this in your question and I wouldn't have given a different comment. A simple way to do that is to add a comment in the `main` method right above your printing statements, for example `// I would write these as proper unit tests, if I wasn't limited by the online editor`

Comment: Makes sense, I will now remember to mention in the question.